# Can't suspend or hibernate system (Manjaro)

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, manjaro

I'm new to Manjaro, recently tried to install NVIDIA 340 for my GeForce 210 but was unsuccessful and continued with video-linux.

When I attempt to suspend, the monitor and disk go off but the system entirely still on and I have to stop system manually.

```
> uname -r
5.15.12-1-MANJARO
```

```
> journalctl --boot=-1 --priority=3
Jan 07 08:24:26 sys kernel: asus_atk0110: Resources not safely usable due to acpi_enforce_resources kernel parameter
Jan 07 08:24:27 sys kernel: asus_atk0110: Resources not safely usable due to acpi_enforce_resources kernel parameter
Jan 07 08:24:29 sys kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: conn 01:0261: func 08 lookup failed, -2
Jan 07 08:24:29 sys avahi-daemon[294]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
Jan 07 08:24:41 sys systemd[641]: Failed to start Update XDG user dir configuration.
Jan 07 08:25:55 sys pulseaudio[868]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possibl>
Jan 07 08:27:01 sys kernel: ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'
```

Comment: My guess is that for hibernate the GPU's VRAM has to be saved (to be restored later). That needs to tell the kernel how to read and save (and restore) the VRAM, and you need (swap) space to save that VRAM in addition to the system RAM. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, But I have 4 GBs of RAM and 4`s for swap too, and a lot of free space on the disk and I even checked my disk for bad sectors but there was no problem.

Comment: And how much VRAM does your video card have?

Comment: I have 1GB dedicated.

Comment: So "RAM + VRAM < swap space". I suggest to extend your swap space to hold all the ram + VRAM + a small reserve. Maybe start presenting syslog messages, too.